# Wordpress - image's absolute path within a function

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress theme for general release. I want to display an image beside the "previous post/next post" (if there the function is true), however, relative paths aren't showing up. Here's the code:

```
<?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Newer posts <img src="/wp-content/themes/basix/images/icons/arrow_right.gif" alt="previous post icon" />', 'basix' )) ?>
```

The image doesn't show up, removing the first forward slash also doesn't work. I was trying to use absolute paths using `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')`, but this function just outputs the html characters, seperate from the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **get_bloginfo()** **not bloginfo()** - **get_bloginfo()** returns the value as **bloginfo()** echo'es it.